# Is there an undo for adding activities in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I'm working through the *Android Studio* tutorials, specifically [Android Fundamentals, 1.4 Learning to help yourself](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-available-resources/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#3), and just learned the following method for adding activities: right-click the *Java* folder and select from **New > Activity > Gallery**.

Is there a way to cleanly *Undo* this action? Or does each class and layout (and other items?) entered have to be individually deleted?

[To all prospective tutorial writers. For every significant action explained, please include how to *verify* and how to *undo*. It's really helpful!]

Answer (score 0):

The option **Edit > Undo** exists, but in the case of having added a *Navigation Drawer Activity*, I get a message that lists 32 files that have a change that cannot be undone.

So, it appears there is no simple, clean way to roll back this change.

Comment: you can use git

Comment: @Abhishek Choudhary - if you are inclined to create an "answer" that shows how to do this, I will, at the least + it for being useful if not actually making it an answer. Having a ready plan to save state where one can roll back would be great.

Comment: I should have said it more clearly, I assumed that you are aware of version control with git (I still assume). I have used git in my projects very less number of times so I just gave you the hint, for now I am not in the state of guiding (creating and answer) you with VCS. Sorry ^_^